# Why there is royal lily in site decoration?

Tags: discussion, design

This symbol ([image: sample taken from screenshot]) displayed between a question and comments. It looks more heraldic than mathematic.

Why is it in the design of math.stackexchange.com? It seems to be more appropriate for, for example, french.stackexchange.com.

Comment: It classes the place up a bit.

Comment: @T.Bongers, For a classed up place there is MathOverflow.

Comment: It's definitely because it's pretty, and under no circumstances does it have anything to do with deep and strong ties to the French monarchy. I'm not quite sure what possibly could have given that idea. 
l'absurdité...

Comment: There is both fancy line with the symbol and also usual line below.

Comment: The real question is why is this image a sad 1x PNG, and not a SVG like the site logo.

Comment: Well, Mathematics is the Queen of Sciences. What did you expect?

Comment: @quid, what about philosophy.stackexchange.com then?

Comment: @T.Bongers: I agree, and it properly classes up the place. Due to Russell's paradox about the site of all sites which are not sites of themselves.

Comment: In case you didn't know, the last French king's reign ended almost 200 years ago... Not many people are attached to royalist traditions here, I don't know why you think it would be "more appropriate" for french.se. It's also present in many other countries' heraldry.

Answer (score 7):

We are holding on to the lily until [French Language](http://french.stackexchange.com) site graduates and gets own design.

My exhaustive/exhausting search determined that only **three** Stack Exchange sites have this design element (which is technically a background image for questions):

- [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/)
- [Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/)
- [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/)

A mathematician, a rabbi, and a cook walk into a bar...

Comment: Now you've started that joke, I challenge you to finish it.

Comment: What's red, hangs on the wall, and whistles?

Comment: Maybe the joke will deal with proving if some food is kosher or not.

Comment: You essentially described one colleague of mine. And since you didn't require nontriviality from the joke, they can all be the same person.

Comment: @WillJagy A herring of course.

Comment: @DanielFischer, yes. My high school friend Paul said this was his father's favorite joke. Online, they seem to use green as often as red. But they do get the general idea of a short dialogue, with objections and responses.